# I am getting multer error : unexpected field when i was trying to upload files in aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I am done with all setup of the s3 bucket and using the correct secret keys,

I want to upload a file from my application using nodejs APIs for uploading and get the file URL from the s3 bucket

here is my code:

```
require("dotenv").config()

const express = require('express')

const app = express();

app.listen(3001,()=>{
   console.log("Runnning.......")
});

const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const multer = require('multer')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');


aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.REGION,
});
const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET
const s3 = new aws.S3();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    acl: "public-read",
    bucket: BUCKET,
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
  })
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async function (req, res, next) {

  res.send('Successfully uploaded ' + req.file.location + ' location!')

})
```

Comment: I think the app.post('/upload', `upload.single('file')` is not correct here, this function needs to handle the req, res, next objects, because it is a middleware

Comment: can you please tell me how to correct it ? @SándorBakos

Comment: disregard my comment, I was wrong, my bad, I think that part OK from the documentation, https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Future reference:

- Multer S3 2.x is compatible with AWS SDK 2.x
- Multer S3 3.x is compatible with AWS SDK 3.x

Either upgrade AWS SDK, or downgrade Multer S3 (`npm install multer-s3@2.x.x`).

[Source](https://github.com/anacronw/multer-s3/issues/169#issuecomment-1141044869)

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by downgrading multer-s3 package from version 3 to 2.